# Formatting dynamic columns JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is to write a code that can input new entries to each section without overwriting entries in the next section. Rows are added based on the length of each array of names. Keep in mind that Threshold can vary in length and may not always have the same name for the last entry. Combine Bags and Extra Ice are static arrays excluding the addition of entries to the end of the section and any adjustment made to their position in the column based on the addition of rows to Threshold.

This is result sheet and it is used to create the list of names in the threshold section of the Order Changes sheet:

[image: result sheet]

This is order changes:

[image: Order Changes]

This sheet is form data. Column D contains keywords that help sort the names.

[image]

This is order changes after the function is executed.

[image]

**I was able to  get the desired result using this code. Is there a better way to get the same outcome?**

```
    function addRows(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getSheetByName("result");
  var rd = r.getRange("F1:G" + r.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var o = ss.getSheetByName("Order Changes");
  var f = ss.getSheetByName("Form Data");
  var fd = f.getRange("C1:D" + f.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var a  = o.getRange(1,1, o.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var cb = a.indexOf("Combine Bags");
  var cbAdd = a[cb -1];
  var threshLen = rd.reduce((ar, [f, g]) => {
    if (g.toLowerCase() == "threshold_customer") ar.push([f]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var newThreshLen = fd.reduce((ar, [c, d]) => {
    if (d.toLowerCase() == "threshold") ar.push([c]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var ni = a.indexOf("Extra Ice") + newThreshLen.length;
  var niAdd = a[ni -1];
  var vip = a.indexOf("VIP");
  var vipAdd = a[vip -1];
  Logger.log(ni);
  var comboLen = fd.reduce((ar, [c, d]) => {
    if (d.toLowerCase() == "combine bags") ar.push([c]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var iceLen = fd.reduce((ar, [c, d]) => {
    if (d.toLowerCase() == "extra ice") ar.push([c]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if(vipAdd.toLowerCase() != ""){
   ss.insertRowsAfter(vip, iceLen.length); 
  }
  if(cbAdd.toLowerCase() != ""){
    ss.insertRowsAfter(cb, newThreshLen.length);
  }
  if(niAdd.toLowerCase()  != ""){
   ss.insertRowsAfter(ni, comboLen.length); 
  }
}
```

The above code adds rows to the end of each section in the Order Changes Sheet based on the number of entries to be added.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `a consistent way to create rows for each section based on the number of entries for the appended list in each section.`. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample input and output situation as images? By the way, the current image in your question is the input situation?

Comment: The current image is the output location. I will add an example for you of what should happen.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have some questions. 1. What is the sheet of `I have a column of names similar to this example:`? 2. What is the sheet of `I take names from sheet 2 based on criteria in column D`? 3. What is the sheet of `Names and rows are added to a specific section. Additions are highlighted yellow to make it easier to see the additions.`? In your script, the sheet names of `result`, `Order Changes` and `Form Data` are used. Unfortunately, I cannot distinguish about your 3 images and your scripts. I apologize for this.

Comment: updated post please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about the correct sheet names, from your updated question, I could understand that you have 4 sheets of `result sheet`, `order changes`, `form data` and `order changes after the function is executed`. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic for retrieving `result sheet` from `order changes`, `form data` and `order changes after the function is executed`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Order Changes = Order changes after the function is executed. Same sheet. There are only 3 sheets. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that `order changes` is the same with `This is order changes after the function is executed.`. As the next step, can I ask you about the relationship between `result sheet`, `order changes` and `form data`?

Comment: Order changes is where data from form data sheet and result sheet is stored after functions are executed.

Comment: I have written a solution to the original post. If there is any way to improve the structure of the code, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I could understand that your script works and you want to reduce the process cost of your script. In this case, in order to replicate your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? I would like to check the result using the sample Spreadsheet and your script, and think of the modification points.